# signal synthesis analysis using STFT

Tags: signals, dft, frequency-analysis

I need to transfer the signal into frequency domain and after some modification, again transfer back in time domain using STFT and ISTFT. By using the same window for analyzing and synthesizing the perfect reconstruction will be obtained. However, if I select two these windows different I wont get full reconstruction. The original signal and reconstructed one is different by a scale which is a function of frame advance as far as I have observed.
It would be nice if you can help me to solve the problem to get the full reconstruction?

```
x             = sin(t)
Nfft          = 256;
Frame_advance = 0.5*Nfft;
window_a       = hann(1500);
window_s       = hann(Nfft);
X  = STFT(x,Nfft,Frame_advance,window_a)
x2 = ISTFT(X,Nfft,Frame_advance,window_s) % reconstructed
```

Comment: why do you need to apply a window to your data? isn't your signal periodic in nature?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your STFT and ISTFT functions, are you using phase information too ?

here my example step by step **(no windowing)** :

```
    %get some point for example 2048 points of signal
    x=signal(1:2048);
    %Make FFT
    y=fft(x);
    %Amplitude of the FFT
    mx=abs(y);
    %get Phase Information
    ma=angle(y);
    %back the signal to complex
    y2= mx .* ( cos(ma) + sqrt(-1) *(sin(ma)) );
    %Apply Inverse FFT
    x2=real(ifft(y2));
```

Now x == x2

In your example are you applying one Hann Window in your signal, then if you apply windowing you need make a OLA [(Overlap and add)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method) process to make a correct reconstruction ...

But why do you need different window size ?